# Calculate the mean and std of images in a HuggingFace image dataset

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I have created a HuggingFace dataset using `imagefolder`:

```py
from dataset import load_dataset

ds = load_dataset("imagefolder", data_files=...)
```

The image files have different sizes, i.e. width and height values.
Now, I would like to simply extract the average and standard deviation of each image per channel. For that, I use the following function and the `map` method:

```py
def calculate_features(example):
  img_mean = np.mean(example["image"], axis=(0, 1))
  img_std = np.std(example["image"], axis=(0, 1))
  example["features"] = np.concatenate((img_mean, img_std), axis=-1)
  return example

ds = ds.map(calculate_features)
```

However, this turns out to be very slow, almost 10 examples per second are processed. If I use `num_proc=4` or `batched=True`, it only becomes just a bit faster (around 2x), not a lot. I guess I am doing something wrong and did some research about using `dataset`, `map`, etc; however, I couldn't find any hint or way to make this faster.